# Splitting output of a string into separate strings

Tags: string, powershell, dns, active-directory

I've been working on a powershell script and it's been really boggling my mind. There are 2 parts to the script.

1. First part is a function that gets all servers in a domain. We have 4 different domains, so I check each one individually and output the result.
2. Second part is a function that outputs the software on a specific remote machine. In my case, the output from the function above will be seeded into this function to see if a server has a particular piece of software installed.

The function that searches the software works properly. The function that I am getting an output of all the servers is what I am having trouble with.

The issue is, that when I output the list of servers (the output is correct), it outputs everything into a single large multiline string...

For example lets say I have 5 servers: (ServerA, ServerB, ServerC, ServerD, ServerE).

When I run the code I will get an output of all the servers for each domain like so:

```
TestA.com

ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
ServerD
ServerE

TestB.com

ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
ServerD
ServerE

TestC.com

ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
ServerD
ServerE

TestD.com

ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
ServerD
ServerE
```

However each domain output is all 1 string, so I can't seed it into the function to check software because it's trying to find it in "ServerA,ServerB,ServerC,ServerD,ServerE", instead of each server individually.

I hope this makes sense. Here is my code to get the list of servers.

```
#Clear Screen
CLS

function Get-Servers
{
    #Variables
    [array]$MyDomains="TestA.com","TestB.com","TestC.com","TestD.com"
    [array]$MySearchBase="dc=TestA,dc=com","dc=TestB,dc=com","dc=TestC,dc=com","dc=TestD,dc=com"


    for($i=0; $i -lt $MyDomains.Count; $i++)
    {
        Write-Output $($MyDomains[$i])

        $MyServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*"' -Properties Name -SearchBase $($MySearchBase[$i]) -Server $($MyDomains[$i]) | Format-Table Name -HideTableHeaders | out-string

        foreach ($MyServer in $MyServers)
        {
            $MyServer
            pause
        }   
    }
}

#Get list of servers
Get-Servers
```

How can I get the output for each server individually to be stored in the "$MyServer" variable?

EDIT:
Here is my function to find remote software

```
function Get-RemoteRegistryProgram
{
  <#
    .Synopsis
      Uses remote registry to read installed programs
    .DESCRIPTION
      Use dot net and the registry key class to query installed programs from a 
      remote machine
    .EXAMPLE
      Get-RemoteRegistryProgram -ComputerName Server1
  #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
            Position=0)]
        [string[]]
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
    begin
    {
        $hives = @(
            [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,
            [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser
        )

        $nodes = @(
            "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
            "Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        )
    }
    process
    {
        $ComputerName

        forEach ($computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            forEach($hive in $hives)
            {
                try
                {
                    $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive,$computer)
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw $PsItem
                }
                forEach($node in $nodes)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        $keys = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).GetSubKeyNames()

                        forEach($key in $keys)
                        {
                            $displayname = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).OpenSubKey($key).GetValue('DisplayName')

                            if($displayname)
                            {
                                $installedProgram = @{
                                   # ComputerName = $computer
                                    DisplayName = $displayname
                                   # Version = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).OpenSubKey($key).GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                                }
                                New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $installedProgram
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        $orginalError = $PsItem
                        Switch($orginalError.FullyQualifiedErrorId)
                        {
                            'InvokeMethodOnNull' 
                            {
                                #key maynot exists
                            }
                            default 
                            {
                                throw $orginalError 
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

If I modify my server function like so:

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $MyDomains.Count; $i++)
{
    Write-Output $($MyDomains[$i])

    $MyServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*"' -Properties Name -SearchBase $($MySearchBase[$i]) -Server $($MyDomains[$i]) | Format-Table Name -HideTableHeaders

    foreach ($MyServer in $MyServers)
    {
        Get-RemoteRegistryProgram -ComputerName $MyServer
    }   

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found.
"
At line:47 char:21
+                     $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. If you want to get installed software on remote computers, you use a script I wrote a while back: [Auditing 32-Bit and 64-Bit Applications with PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/auditing-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-powershell).

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to sound ignorant but I'm trying to run this and having some trouble. I have a server.txt file I try to use.

Get-Content u:\scripts\servers.txt | get-installedapp2 -Publisher "*SysAid*"

I'm getting an error with your code.

Comment: 1) You did not tell what error (remember, nobody can see your screen). 2) Where did the `2` come from on the end of `Get-InstalledApp`? The script name does not have a `2` on the end of it.

Comment: This is your function: 
function get-installedapp2($computerName) {

and in your process I see:
if ($PIPELINEINPUT) 
    {
        get-installedapp2 $_
    } 
    else 
    {
        $ComputerName | foreach-object { get-installedapp2 $_ }
    }

Comment: Feel free to read the article. It provides examples.

Comment: I got it figured out. I was getting some access denied errors which is strange because I am domain admin and have access to all the servers. Either case I got my script working the way I need it to. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting some things and fixing my issue. To avoid the string issue, I export the results to a text file and then using get-content I read line by line from the text file and seeded each server to let me know which servers have the software I need. Here is the end result.

```
#Clear Screen
CLS

function Get-RemoteRegistryProgram
{
  <#
    .Synopsis
      Uses remote registry to read installed programs
    .DESCRIPTION
      Use dot net and the registry key class to query installed programs from a 
      remote machine
    .EXAMPLE
      Get-RemoteRegistryProgram -ComputerName Server1
  #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)][string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)][string]$SoftwareName
    )
    begin
    {
        $hives = @(
            [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,
            [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser
        )

        $nodes = @(
            "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
            "Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        )
    }
    process
    {
        $ComputerName
        $skip = $false

        forEach ($computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            forEach($hive in $hives)
            {
                try
                {
                    $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive,$computer)
                }
                catch
                {
                    $skip = $true                
                }

                if($skip -eq $false)
                {
                    forEach($node in $nodes)
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            $keys = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).GetSubKeyNames()

                            forEach($key in $keys)
                            {
                                $displayname = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).OpenSubKey($key).GetValue('DisplayName')

                                #Modified by James
                                if(($displayname) -like "*$SoftwareName*")
                                {
                                    $displayname + "`t" + $computer >> c:\scripts\sysaidServers.txt
                                }

                                <# Modified by James
                                if($displayname)
                                {
                                    $installedProgram = @{
                                       # ComputerName = $computer
                                        DisplayName = $displayname
                                       # Version = $registry.OpenSubKey($node).OpenSubKey($key).GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                                    }
                                    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $installedProgram
                                }
                                #>
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        <#
                            $orginalError = $PsItem
                            Switch($orginalError.FullyQualifiedErrorId)
                            {
                                'InvokeMethodOnNull' 
                                {
                                    #key maynot exists
                                }
                                default 
                                {
                                    throw $orginalError 
                                }
                            }
                        #>
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end
    {

    }
}

#Output the servers to a txt file
function Get-Servers
{
    param ([Parameter( Mandatory=$true)][string]$SaveFile)

    #Variables
    [array]$MyDomains="DomainA.com","DomainB.com","DomainC.com","DomainD.com"
    [array]$MySearchBase="dc=DomainA,dc=com","dc=DomainB,dc=com","dc=DomainC,dc=com","dc=DomainD,dc=com"


    for($i=0; $i -lt $MyDomains.Count; $i++)
    {
        #I only want servers running Windows Server OS
        $MyServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*"' -Properties Name -SearchBase $($MySearchBase[$i]) -Server $($MyDomains[$i]) | Format-Table Name -HideTableHeaders | out-string
        #Remove all whitespace and export to txt file
        $MyServers.Trim() -replace (' ', '') >> $SaveFile
    }
}

function CheckServerSoftware
{
    param ([Parameter( Mandatory=$true)][string]$SaveFile)

    Get-Content $SaveFile | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match $regex)
        {
            $computer = $_.ToString()
            Get-RemoteRegistryProgram -ComputerName $computer.Trim() $SoftwareName
            Write-Output ""
        }
    }
}

#Path to where our exported server list is
$SaveFile = "c:\scripts\servers.txt"
$SoftwareName = "SysAid"

#If the file already exists, remove it
Remove-Item $SaveFile

#Create the text file with servers
Get-Servers $SaveFile

#Import our server list and check software on each server
CheckServerSoftware $SaveFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is converting the server names to a string

`$MyServers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*"' -Properties Name -SearchBase $($MySearchBase[$i]) -Server $($MyDomains[$i]) | Format-Table Name -HideTableHeaders | out-string`

The last part of that is `out-string`. Instead of piping to a format table and pushing it out as a string, keep the objects and use the properties in each object to get the names of each server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I remove out-string, that works, however, then I am unable to feed the value into my software function. I get an error message

"
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found.
"
At line:47 char:21
+                     $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey ...

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
"

Comment: I updated my original post to include the software function.

If I made the adjustments as you mentioned above and call the function like this: Get-RemoteRegistryProgram -ComputerName $MyServer